# 3d button animation in svg

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have a 3d button and I would like to simulate the pressure of a click, when a click is made. I used `:active` to hide one level(full button) and show another(button pressed), only it's not a smooth animation. I would like to have a smooth animation.

[image]

Comment: Instead of hiding/showing layers, transition one layer to move between the states.  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put together a codepen example with one of the possible answers [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgBWJm).

It is very crude, but you can improve it easily. The speed of the animation can be tweaked at the `transition` property in the css, longer times lead to slower movement. The first circle provides a background and some illusion of perspective, but you can also design a custom path.

By the way, you may want to consider using codepen or other alternatives to provide a working example when posting a question. It is an easy way to comply with the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

*EDIT after comment*:

Here is a more detailed example of what I had in mind, trying to get closer to your example. Rather than providing a simple protocol for your question, I would like this answer to be useful if you are serious about `svg` and `css`. I am learning myself. A couple of points in this regard:

- You seem to have created the `svg` code with an editor. Nothing wrong with that, but it makes other tasks much harder. I have created this example from scratch with an editor.
- Probably because of that, you have a viewBox at the start that changes the coordinate system. I have kept it, but, AFAIKT, in this setting it serves no purpose.
- The shadow in your example is an array of ellipses. This is a convenient way to create custom color gradients, but it is cumbersome if you are editing it. I have replaced this with a linear gradient. The animation techniques in my answer can also be used with the original gradient.
- When saving, you probably used the setting `Save text as paths` or something to that effect. The text `BIOGRAFIA` is not actual text, and it would be hard to edit afterwards (say you want to translate it to some other language).

Your original question is about a smooth transition. If you want to simulate the push of a button, you need to move the cylinder and the shade, rather than make them appear/disappear. To create the illusion that the button is being pressed, I have set the following elements:

- A composite object with a circle and a path for the button (id `cyl`). This means that the top of the button has a different class (`darker`) and can be changed independently. By the way, the path contains a gradient fill similar to the one you used (id `SVGID_1_mp`).
- A path filled with a linear gradient for the shade (id `shadeShape`).
- Two `clipPath` elements in the header to create the illusion that a part of the button or the shadow is disappearing. As you can see, the `clip-path` declaration is outside the path in a parental `g` element, like this:

```
    <g clip-path='url(#cyl2)'>
      <use xlink:href="#cyl" id="butanim" x="100" y="150" />
    </g>
```

With this setting, we can animate the `butanim` element and keep the `clip-path` fixed.

It is also important to notice that, for the shade to move at the same time as the button, both must be inside the same element (id `banim`). This also means that the animation will also be triggered by pushing the shadow. I have found no way around this limitation. Both animations are linke by the `--button-press-time` css variable at the start of the `css` section.

I have learned other interesting details while preparing this example, but I think it would be best for you to tinker with the example. You can also find it [here](https://codepen.io/mohingudino/pen/zgBWJm?editors=1100#0).

```css
:root{
  --button-press-time: 0.4s
}

#butanim{
  transition: transform var(--button-press-time, 0.2s) ease;
  stroke: #000000;
  fill: url(#SVGID_1_mp);
}

#shade{
  fill: url(#shadeGradient);
  transition: transform var(--button-press-time, 0.2s) ease;
}

#banim:active #butanim{
  transform: translate(42.4px, 42.4px);
}

#banim:active #shade{
  transform: translate(34.2px, -94.6px);
}

#btext{
  fill: #FF8B0D;
}

.darker{
  fill: #f4971a;
  stroke: none;
}
.mybutton{
  stroke: none;
}

.outline{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div >Push the button</div>
    <svg class="svgfig" version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 309 330" style="enable-background:new 0 0 309 330;" xml:space="preserve" width="90" height="150">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_mp" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#F4971A" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#A76101" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="shadeGradient" x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.4" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0.1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="shadePath">
          <path d="M -50 0 a 50 50 0 0 0 100 0 l 10 -90 a 60 60 0 0 0 -110 0 Z" transform="translate(142.4 192.4) rotate(200)" />
        </clipPath>
        <path d="M -50 0 a 50 50 0 0 0 100 0 l 10 -90 a 60 60 0 0 0 -110 0 Z" transform="translate(142.4 192.4) rotate(200)" id="shadeShape"/>
        <g id="cyl">
        <path d="M -50 0 a 50 50 0 0 0 100 0 l 0 -60 a 50 50 0 0 0 -100 0 Z" transform="rotate(135)" class="mybutton" />
          <circle x="0" y="0" r="50" class="darker" />
        </g>
        <clipPath id="cyl2"> <path d="M -50 0 a 50 50 0 0 0 100 0 l 0 -60 a 50 50 0 0 0 -100 0 Z" transform="translate(100 150) rotate(135)" />
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <circle class="outline" cx="142.2" cy="192.2" r="60" />
        <g id="banim">
          <g clip-path='url(#shadePath)'>
            <use xlink:href="#shadeShape" id="shade" />
          </g>
          <g clip-path='url(#cyl2)'>
            <use xlink:href="#cyl" id="butanim" x="100" y="150" />
          </g>
        </g>
        <text id='btext' x="161" y="80" font-size="24" font-family="sans-serif" font-weight="700">BIOGRAFIA</text>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a good idea to use two circles.

link to my example

`codepen `[link][1]


  [1]: https://codepen.io/legolas82/pen/zgKxpV